# Can I have a non-mutable IEnumerable<>?

Tags: c#, .net

I have code similar to this:

```
class Foo
{
   List<Bar> _myList;
   ...
   public IEnumerable<Bar> GetList() { return _myList; }
}
```

The result of GetList() should **NOT** be mutable.

To clarify, it is ok if instances of Bar are modified.
I simply want to make sure the collection itself is not modified.

I'm sure I read an answer somewhere on SO where someone pointed this was possible, but for the life of me, I can't find it again.

Comment: There must be something I am missing here: the question seems illogical to me, and all the answers seem pointless, because as far as I can tell, `IEnumerable<>` is already non-mutable.   (By the way, ***non-mutable*** is called ***immutable***.)  So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answers already provided will work absolutely fine, but I just thought I'd add that you can use the *AsReadOnly* extension method in .NET 3.5, as such:

```
class Foo
{
   List<Bar> _myList;
   ...
   public ReadOnlyCollection<Bar> GetList() { return _myList.AsReadOnly(); }
}
```

Comment: @Benoit these are at the collection level, see my answer for more info  about that

Comment: Yeah, extension methods always make things nice. Note that there also exist the AsEnumerable and AsQueryable extension methods for similar circumstances.

Comment: (Although AsEnumerable seems might seem like a particularly useless function at first, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx for an explanation.)

Comment: There must be something I am missing here: the question seems illogical to me, and all the answers seem pointless, because as far as I can tell, `IEnumerable<>` is already non-mutable.   (By the way, ***non-mutable*** is called ***immutable***.)  So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

You can use System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<Bar> GetList() {return new ReadOnlyCollection<Bar>(_myList);}
```

Comment: carefull, you can still modify Bar instances.

Answer (score 1):

```
return new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<Bar>(_myList);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.objectmodel.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent Bar elements from being modified at the Collection level. If you only want it Not mutable regarding add/delete/etc use ReadOnlyCollection.

If you instead need to enforce that each element isn't mutable, then you have to enforce that in the Bar class i.e. don't have setters or any method that changes the state of Bar.

Answer (score 0):

You could expose IEnumerable from a ReadOnlyCollecton or you could do something like this (assuming LINQ):

```
public IEnumerable<Bar> GetList() { return (from item in _myList select item); }
```